# can $u$ attain a local maxima at $x_0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

> Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, connected, open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and $u$ is real analytic on $\Bbb R^n$. Let $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}=0, \forall i=1,\dots, n$ then can $u$ attain a local maxima at $x_0$ ?

I know that at a point of Maxima, the total derivative of the function must vanish and its Hessian is $\le 0$. But what happens if we know it is exactly equal to 0, i do not know.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Think of an upside-down parabola…

Comment: Yes, it can. Consider e.g. $f(x,y)=-(x^4+y^4)$ at $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0).$